# Issue in getting current state of TableModel while refreshing JTable row content on Refresh button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, classcastexception, tablemodel

[image: Mutual Funds Tracker Application]
I am trying to create the above Java application using Swing. The use case is that on the highlighted "Refresh" button click, I wanted to loop every row in the funds list table shown on the right and fetch the Scheme Codes for each individual fund(so that I could search them for their current corresponding NAV values using a web-service call).

Code for the above application src code files:

**TablePanel.java** (*the left section of the app screen*)

```
public class TablePanel extends JPanel {

private JTable table;
private FundsTableModel fundsModel;
private JPopupMenu popup;
private FundsTableListener fundsTableListener;
private JLabel lblSum;
JTable tableSorted;
JTableHeader header ;
JTableHeader tableHeader;

public TablePanel() {
    fundsModel = new FundsTableModel();
    table = new JTable(fundsModel);
    popup = new JPopupMenu();
    lblSum = new JLabel();
    header = table.getTableHeader();
    
    JMenuItem removeItem = new JMenuItem("Delete Row");
    popup.add(removeItem);
    
    table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new SimpleHeaderRenderer());
    
    //Show "Delete" popup
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            
            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                popup.show(table, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });
    
    removeItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            if(fundsTableListener != null) {
                fundsTableListener.rowDeleted(row);
                fundsModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
            }
        }
    });
    
    //Sort Table rows
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(table.getModel());
                table.setRowSorter(sorter);
                ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>(2);
                 
                JTableHeader tableHeader = (JTableHeader)e.getSource();
                int selectedColumn = 0;
                selectedColumn = tableHeader.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(selectedColumn, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
                
                sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
                sorter.sort();
            }});                
    
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(lblSum, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
public void setData(List<Fund> db) {
    fundsModel.setData(db);
}
public void refresh() {
    addTotalRow();
    fundsModel.fireTableDataChanged();
}

private void addTotalRow() {
    fundsModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            int numberOfRow = fundsModel.getRowCount();
            System.out.println("Number of rows: "+numberOfRow);
            float currValueSum = 0.0f,currAmtInvestedSum = 0.0f,currTotalMargin = 0.0f;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
                float value1 = Float.valueOf(fundsModel.getValueAt(i, 7).toString());
                float value2 = Float.valueOf(fundsModel.getValueAt(i, 8).toString());
                float value3 = Float.valueOf(fundsModel.getValueAt(i, 9).toString());
                currValueSum += value1;
                currAmtInvestedSum += value2;
                currTotalMargin += value3;
            }
            lblSum.setText("Curr Value: " +(currValueSum)+" \t | \t Invested Amt: " +(currAmtInvestedSum)+" \t | \t Margin: " +(currTotalMargin));
        }
    });
}   
public void setFundsTableListener(FundsTableListener listener) {
    this.fundsTableListener = listener;
}
```

}

**FundsTableModel.java** (*my tablemodel class*)

```
public class FundsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
private List<Fund> db;
private String[] colNames = {"Fund Name","Fund Code","Scheme Code","Scheme Name","Category","Folio No.","Units","Current Value","Amt Invested","Margin", "Select"};

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return colNames[column];
}
public void setData(List<Fund> db) {
    this.db = db;
}
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 11;
}
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return db.size();
}
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Fund fund = db.get(row);
    
    switch (col) {
    case 0:
        return fund.getFundName();
    case 1:
        return fund.getFundCode();
    ...
    }   
    return null;
}
}
```

**FormPanel.java** (*the right section of the app where the jtable with funds list is displayed*)

```
public class FormPanel extends JPanel {

private JLabel fundNameLabel, ....;
private JButton addBtn, resetBtn, refreshBtn;
private FormListener formListener;
private JTable table;
private FundsTableModel fundsModel;

public FormPanel() {
    Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
    dim.width = 360;    //Shrinking this value will collapse the textfields
    setPreferredSize(dim);
    
    fundNameLabel = new JLabel("FundName: ");
    . . .
    Boolean selection  = new Boolean(false);
    
    fundNameList = new JComboBox<String>();
    categoryList = new JComboBox<String>();
    addBtn = new JButton("Add");
    resetBtn = new JButton("Reset");
    refreshBtn = new JButton("Refresh");
    
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> fundNameModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    fundNameModel.addElement("ADITYABIRLA");
    . . .
    fundNameList.setModel(fundNameModel);
    
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> fundCategoryModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    fundCategoryModel.addElement("EQUITY");
    fundCategoryModel.addElement("ELSS");
    categoryList.setModel(fundCategoryModel);

    table = new JTable(fundsModel);
    
    addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //code to fetch values from fields
            FormEvent ev = new FormEvent(this, fundName, fundCode, schemeCode, schemeName, category, folioId, units, currValue, amtInvested, margin, selection);
            
            if(formListener != null) {
                formListener.formEventOccurred(ev);
            }
        }
    });
    
    resetBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            //code to reset fields
        }
    });
    
    refreshBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                    //Loop through the number of rows & get the scheme code of each row     
                    FundsTableModel ftm = (FundsTableModel)table.getModel();
                    int numberOfRow = ftm.getRowCount();
                    System.out.println(numberOfRow);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
                        
                        int value1 = Integer.valueOf(ftm.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                        System.out.println(value1);  
                    }
        } 
    });
    
    Border innerBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Add Fund");
    Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(innerBorder, outerBorder));
    layoutComponents();
}

private void layoutComponents() {...}

public void setFormListener(FormListener listener) {
    this.formListener = listener;
}
}
```

The issue is in the below code block where I try to get the current state of the TableModel:

```
refreshBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                    //Loop through the number of rows & get the scheme code of each row     
                    FundsTableModel ftm = (FundsTableModel)table.getModel();

                    int numberOfRow = ftm.getRowCount();
                    System.out.println(numberOfRow);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {

                        int value1 = Integer.valueOf(ftm.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                        System.out.println(value1);  
                    }
        } 
    });
```

On the **Refresh** button click in the app, I get the following **ClassCastException** when trying to fetch current state of TableModel:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel cannot be cast to gui.FundsTableModel
at gui.FormPanel$3.actionPerformed(FormPanel.java:146)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
. . .
```

From a previous similar question asked on this portal, from JB Nizet's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27127719/2455277), I came to know that clearing the table data solves the issue there. Is my issue also based on the same lines? Please pardon my limited knowledge in implementing TableModel class before.

Also, this a previous code that I was having which also generates a **NPE** when used in the place of the above FormPanel.java code. The first line of refreshBtn.actionPerformed gives the **NPE** when accessing fundsModel.getRowCount():

```
public class FormPanel extends JPanel {

private JLabel fundNameLabel;
...
private JTable table;
private FundsTableModel fundsModel;

public FormPanel() {
    Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
    dim.width = 360;    //Shrinking this value will collapse the textfields
    setPreferredSize(dim);
    ...
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    table = new JTable(model);
    addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});
    resetBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...});
    
    fundsModel = new FundsTableModel();
    refreshBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Loop through the number of rows & get the scheme code of each row 
                        int numberOfRow = fundsModel.getRowCount();
                        System.out.println(numberOfRow);
                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
                          int value1 = Integer.valueOf(fundsModel.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
                          System.out.println(value1);  
                    }
                        model.fireTableDataChanged();
        } 
    }); 
    
    Border innerBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Add Fund");
    Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(innerBorder, outerBorder));
    layoutComponents();
}

private void layoutComponents() {...}
public void setFormListener(FormListener listener) {...}
```

}

Could someone please shred some light on how to proceed with fetching (and printing) the "**Scheme Code**" values on click of Refresh button for now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what that `rowSorter(…)` method is doing in your FundsTableModel. The `getColumnClass(…)` code should be part of your FundsTableModel, not that method.

Comment: You can ignore rowsorter() method code as I had initially written that method to be called from FundsTableModel() constructor which was removed later.

Comment: A severely reduced [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be preferred to a few swathes of code. Just the code that highlights the problem, strip all the rest.